# How to detect email servers with MX records redirecting to another MX server

Tags: mx-record

We have a project to identify mail servers which has MX record re-directing to another MX server. Does anyone has any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: Look for mail servers with multiple RDNS entries, or RDNS entries which don't correspond to the FQDN?

Comment: Could you clarify a bit? What servers - any servers all over the internet? What do you mean by re-directing? What is the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Comment: do you mean cases where `MX domain.com` points to `host.domain.com` and `MX host.domain.com` points to `otherhost.domain.com`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do by:

> - query MX record i.e MX record of abc.com point to mail.abc.com
> - Find IP of mail.abc.com i.e ping mail.abc.com
> - Find PTR of IP of mail.abc.com i.e host -t PTR

Compare the result, if `PTR of IP of mail.abc.com` not equal `mail.abc.com` then MX record point to another mail server.